# Fullcalendar issue with past

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a small issue in that if i drop an event into the past it accepts this. I'm using version 2.4.

I've tried using [eventConstraint](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventConstraint/) but it doesn't work.

How could i go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

eventConstraint should work

[Disable drop on past dates in FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496695/disable-drop-on-past-dates-in-fullcalendar)

```
/* This constrains it to today or +5 years */
eventConstraint: {
    start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    end: moment().add(365*5, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
}
```