# Jquery full calendar disable the past date

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

how to disable the past date in fullcalendar.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false,
    selectable: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    views: {
      agenda: {
        eventLimit: 1 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
      }
    },
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      var check = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      var today = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      if (check >= today) {
        $('.addClass').addClass('sticky');
      }
    }

  });
```

this my code working fine, I can select from new Date only `addClass` also working fine. But If I select next month date the `addClass` is not working. **Note** I want to do this click only by using `select` option, not on `dayClick`

Comment: Hey! Your goal is to "disable" select in the past?

Comment: @LakiGeri yes I want to disable the past date and month

Comment: Please check your answer already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496695/disable-drop-on-past-dates-in-fullcalendar)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectAllow: function(selectInfo) {
      return moment().diff(selectInfo.start) <= 0
    }
  })

})
```

You can check this link : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZozZeG?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    if(start.isBefore(moment())) {
        alert('Event is start in the past!');
    } else {
       // event ok

    }
}
```

In this method the start is checked, that is that a past date or not.

I suggest you to read the moment.js libary [doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/), what is used by the fullcalendar.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Use "$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});" to disable past month and past date.

For Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
$( "#date" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="date" />
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help you!